# Safari 9 ignores picture element

Tags: html, image, safari, srcset

I am trying to implement art direction and make the `<picture>` element show a square image on mobile and a landscape image on all other devices. For some reason, Safari keeps falling back to the `<img>` tag, when it should be able to recognize the `<source srcset="">` values I've given here.

```
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 480px)" srcset="http://placehold.it/480x480">
  <source media="(max-width: 640px)" srcset="http://placehold.it/640x320">
  <source media="(max-width: 1024px)" srcset="http://placehold.it/1024x600">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1224x1224/c00/fff" alt="">
</picture>
```

This seems to work find in chrome, but can anyone explain why Safari is ignoring these srcset attributes and how I can get it to work in Safari 9? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Safari 9 doesn't support `<picture>`, but it looks like Safari 9.1 does!
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9_1.html?ref=webdesignernews.com

Answer (score 1):

Safari 9 doesn't have support for `<picture>`. It only supports `<img srcset>`.
If you need `<picture>` support for Safari, you probably want to add [picturefill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/) to your site.